# Small Images not Zooming using ElevateZoom plugin

Tags: javascript, elevatezoom

I am using ElevateZoom plugin in my application. If the image resolution is good it is able to zoom but when the image resolution is small it's not working.
Here is the code:

**description.jsp**

```
<img ng-if="mlist.typeId===1" 
                            ng-elevate-zoom
                             zoom-image="{{mlist.mediaUrl}}" id="zimg{{$index}}"
                              actual-src="{{mlist.mediaUrl}}" loader-src="resources/images/loading.gif" loader-class="preloader" showloader 
                              class="img-responsive zoomImg" alt=""/>
```

where zoom-image, actual-src data-zoom-image all having same image.

**app.js**

```
app.directive('ngElevateZoom', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          //Will watch for changes on the attribute
          attrs.$observe('zoomImage',function(){
            linkElevateZoom();
          })

          function linkElevateZoom(){
            //Check if its not empty
            if (!attrs.zoomImage) return;
            element.attr('data-zoom-image',attrs.zoomImage);
            $(element).elevateZoom({zoomType:"lens", cursor:"crosshair"/*, lensSize:250*//**/ /*scrollZoom:true*//*, containLensZoom:true*/});
          }

          linkElevateZoom();

        }
      };
    });
```

Plugin : elevatezoom

Comment: Welcome, but where is the code to have a look and fix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask